# Update Mongodb em array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : "55dcb404478e7227203d3a65",
    "Nome" : "Grupo Familia",
    "Pessoas" : [ 
        {
            "PessoaId" : "55dcb425478e72207833e970",
            "Nome" : "Carlos",
            "Habilidades" : [
                {
                    "HabilidadeId" : "55dcb433478e7229b0e3ee07",
                    "Valor" : 20,
                    "Nome": "José"
                },
                {
                    "HabilidadeId" : "55dcb425478e72207833e961",
                    "Valor" : 40,
                    "Nome" : "Vitor"
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Usando o `mongocsharpdriver`, como faço para dar update do tipo `modify` (sem usar o save) no *Array* de Habilidades ?
Consegui uma forma de fazer porém eu preciso do *index* do *array*, mas não sei como encontrá-lo. No exemplo abaixo eu passei o *index* como 0, aí ele pega a primeira pessoa e adiciona a nova habilidade:

```
var novaHabilidade = new Habilidade { };
var update = Update<Grupo>.AddToSet(a => a.Pessoas[0].Habilidades, novaHabilidade);
context.Grupos.Update(Query.EQ("_id", "55dcacb7478e722a60e7c002"), update);
```

Tentei de uma forma diferente, tentando filtrar a pessoa que eu quero:

```
var update = Update<Grupo>.AddToSet(a => a.Pessoas.Find(b => b.PessoaId == "55dcb425478e72207833e970").Habilidades, novaHabilidade);
```

Não obtive êxito, dá o erro de "Referência de objeto não instanciada". Alguém conhece uma forma de fazer? Queria utilizar os objetos que criei, nada de criar `BsonDocument`.

Esse é o erro que está dando "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression"

Comment: Antes de mais nada, você testou se isso aqui devolve valor? `a.Pessoas.Find(b => b.PessoaId == "55dcb425478e72207833e970")`

Comment: Acho que você não pode usar tudo numa linha só. Este erro é bem conhecido, e acontece quando a lib tenta montar a expressão e não consegue. Melhor separar em mais linhas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Como você faria essa operação que eu estou tentando fazer ?

Comment: @GustavoGoisCardoso Vou colocar como resposta. Aliás, acho que você precisa aprender a usar o site. [Veja como aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Aliás, se eu colocar como resposta, vai ser na sintaxe clássica. Esse objeto `Update<T>` eu nunca vi. Nem sei como funciona.

Comment: pode ser na sintaxe clássica !

Answer (score 1):

Descobri como fazer, caso alguém tenha interesse segue:

```
var update = Update.AddToSet("Pessoas.$.Habilidades", novaHabilidade.ToBsonDocument());
var retorno = context.Grupos.Update(Query.EQ("Pessoas.PessoaId", new ObjectId("55de157b478e72231cfeca69")), update);
```